# How to Handle iPhone X, Xs, Xs Max, Xr Screen Edge

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble drawing, scaling, and positioning paths on the iPhone X's in the GameScene. It appears frame.minX is outside the physical bounds of the screen (see images comparing the same code simulated on an iPhone X and an iPhone 8s). How can I handle this screen inset when drawing, scaling, and positioning various SKShapeNodes, SKNodes, SKSpriteNodes, etc.? I'd like to be able to easily reference the true edge of the screen when drawing.

[image: iPhone X]
[image: Other iPhone]

Note that adding subviews works fine (UIViews, buttons, etc. all will align to the edge of the screen if UIScreen.main.bounds is used instead of frame)

I have tried drawing SKShapeNodes when referencing the frame, and screen, but neither can precisely draw at the true edge of the iPhone X screen AND the true edge of other iPhones.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let shape = SKShapeNode()
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)).cgPath
        shape.fillColor = .green
        shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.minX, y: frame.maxY - shape.frame.height)
        addChild(shape)
}
```

For all simulations, the green square is perfectly aligned with the left edge of the screen. However, on the iPhone X, Xs, Xs Max, and Xr, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, I was able to solve the problem shortly after posing the question on StackOverflow. For those who have stumbled on this page with a similar issue:

The problem lies in how the GameScene is drawn with respect to the screen size. Because the screen ratio of the iPhone X is ~19.5:9 (compared to 16:9 on other iPhones), the frame gets cropped.

To resolve this, in the GameViewController.swift, set the `scene.scaleMode` to `.resizeFill` instead of `.aspectFill`:

```
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```

Comment: not the recommended way to fix it.  9 out of 10 times, you want `.aspectFill`,  so you need to design your games around the different aspect ratios, otherwise you are going to offer a completely different experience across various devices.